# Extracting dictionary values from dataframe and creating a new Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have a Pandas DataFrame with several columns, one of which is a dictionary containing coordinates in a list. This is what the entry looks like:

```
{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-120.12345, 50.23456]}
```

I would like to extract this data and create 2 new columns in the original DataFrame, one for the latitude and one for longitude.

| ID | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -120.12345 | 50.23456 |

I have not been able to find a simple solution at this point and would be grateful for any guidance.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-120.12345, 50.23456]}).query('index==1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str` to fetch the required structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col' : [{'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-120.12345, 50.23456]}]})
df['Latitude'] = df.Col.str['coordinates'].str[0]
df['Longitude'] = df.Col.str['coordinates'].str[1]
```

OUTPUT:

```
                                                 Col   Latitude  Longitude
0  {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-120.12345, ... -120.12345   50.23456
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access dictionary get method through the `.str`

```py
test = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2],
        "point": [
            {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-120.12345, 50.23456]},
            {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [-10.12345, 50.23456]}]
    }, 
)

pd.concat([
    test["ID"],
    pd.DataFrame(
        test['point'].str.get('coordinates').to_list(),
        columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude']
)
],axis=1)
```

Comment: When running this I get the following error "ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable". I have attempted to solution this however, no luck.

Comment: Didn't test for more rows! That should do it.